# Why do I need to access `default` in my typescript object?

Tags: typescript, object, default

I'm importing an object that looks like this:

```
{
  "42": {
    "DappToken": [
      "0xa9B96972A81d98AeF3bD252C116e5D18C93a4cc1",
    ],
    "TokenFarm": [
      "0x09c3f825f5347Dbcb59A16DFC83540E034a11511",
    ]
  }
}
```

I'm importing it like so:

```js
import * as networkMapping from "../abis/map.json"
```

And then accessing it like:

```js
const tokenFarmAddressFromMapping = networkMapping["default"][chainId]["TokenFarm"]
```

Why do I need to do `networkMapping["default"][chainId]["TokenFarm"]` instead of just `networkMapping[chainId]["TokenFarm"]` like how I would with regular javascript?

Comment: Because of `* as`, remove it

Comment: Why is this flagged as not reproducible? All the code and imports are here and anyone can reproduce it. It looks like a lot of people were able to reproduce it. I also don't see too many typos. Can we have someone reopen this?

Comment: Right, hence the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have this file:

```
// file-a.ts
export const a = 1
export const b = 2
export default 3
```

Typically you would import it's named exports like this:

```
import { a, b } from './file-a'
```

Or it's default export like this:

```
import defaultExport from './file-a'
```

Or both like this:

```
import defaultExport, { a, b } from './file-a'
```

But when you do `import * as someVar from './file-a'`, you get everything as a single object.

```
import * as fileA from './file-a'

fileA.a // 1
fileA.b // 2
fileA.default // 3
```

Notice how the default export in `file-a.ts` does not have a name. In order to make this work `default` is assigned as the name so that it has a property name to set on the imported object.

If you don't want this behavior, then you simply want to import the default export with this:

```
import fileA from './fileA'
```

---

The other piece is that JSON files do not have named exports at all, only a default export that is a single value. So you can assume that your JSON file is the equivalent of this typescript file:

```
export default {
  "42": {
    "DappToken": [
      "0xa9B96972A81d98AeF3bD252C116e5D18C93a4cc1",
    ],
    "TokenFarm": [
      "0x09c3f825f5347Dbcb59A16DFC83540E034a11511",
    ]
  }
}
```

---

All this means that you want to import your JSON's default export with this simple syntax:

```
import networkMapping from "../abis/map.json"
```